# Display ID with Identity Property from SQL Table in Web Form C# and ASP

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, forms

I have this simple Ticket Tracking software using C# and ASP.net.

My Problem is, I cannot Display or Print the ID value from my database. 
My application works fine and each time I fill out my web form, it updates the database and generates a new ID number.

All my code works as it should except that it does not display the number.

Basically, a user fills out the form and then goes to a Successful Submission page. I want the number to display in the submission page.

Here is my stored procedure

```
USE [TrackITApp]
GO

SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[StoredProcGetSupportTicket]
-- Add the parameters for the stored procedure here
@fname nvarchar(50),
@lname nvarchar(50),
@email nvarchar(50),
@severityID bigint,
@statusID bigint,
@departmentID bigint,
@issuetype bigint,
@issuedesc nvarchar(500),
@ticketnumber bigint OUTPUT
AS
BEGIN
-- SET NOCOUNT ON added to prevent extra result sets from
-- interfering with SELECT statements.
SET NOCOUNT ON;

-- Insert statements for procedure here
INSERT INTO supporticket(fname,lname,email,severityID,statusID,departmentID,issuetype,issuedesc)
VALUES(@fname,@lname,@email,@severityID,@statusID,@departmentID,@issuetype,@issuedesc)

SET @ticketnumber=SCOPE_IDENTITY()
END
```

Here is my Save Class

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace TrackIT
{
    public class SupportTicket
    {
        #region Declarations
        public string fname { get; set; }
        public string lname { get; set; }
        public string email { get; set; }
        public int statusID { get; set; }
        public string issuedesc { get; set; }
        public int severityID { get; set; }
        public int issuetype { get; set; }
        public int departmentID { get; set; }
        public int ticketnum { get; set; }



    #endregion

    #region Methods
    public void Save()
    {

        string constr = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["constr"].ConnectionString;
        using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(constr))
        {
            using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("StoredProcGetSupportTicket"))
            {
                cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

                SqlParameter parameterFName = new SqlParameter("@fname", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

                parameterFName.Value = fname;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterFName);

                SqlParameter parameterLName = new SqlParameter("@lName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

                parameterLName.Value = lname;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterLName);

                SqlParameter parameterEmail = new SqlParameter("@email", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 50);

                parameterEmail.Value = email;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterEmail);

                SqlParameter parameterSeverity = new SqlParameter("@severityID", SqlDbType.BigInt);

                parameterSeverity.Value = severityID;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterSeverity);

                SqlParameter parameterStatus = new SqlParameter("@statusID", SqlDbType.BigInt);

                parameterStatus.Value = statusID;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterStatus);

                SqlParameter parameterDepartment = new SqlParameter("@departmentID", SqlDbType.BigInt);

                parameterDepartment.Value = departmentID;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDepartment);

                SqlParameter parameterissuedesc = new SqlParameter("@issuedesc", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 500);

                parameterissuedesc.Value = issuedesc;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterissuedesc);

                SqlParameter parameterissuetype = new SqlParameter("@issuetype", SqlDbType.BigInt);

                parameterissuetype.Value = issuetype;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterissuetype);

                SqlParameter parameterticketnum = new SqlParameter("@ticketnumber", SqlDbType.BigInt);

                parameterticketnum.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                parameterticketnum.Value = ticketnum;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterticketnum);

                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                int tickID = (int)Convert.ToInt32(ticketnum.ToString());
                con.Close();
                try
                {

                    con.Open();
                    cmd.Connection = con;
                }
                catch (Exception e)
                {
                    throw new Exception(e.Message.ToString());

                }
                finally
                {
                    cmd.Dispose();
                    con.Close();


                }


            }

            #endregion
        }
    }
}
}
```

Lastly, Here is aspx.cs which gets everything to update the database:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace TrackIT
{
    public partial class ticket : System.Web.UI.Page
    {

    #region Declarations
    SupportTicket tk = new SupportTicket();
    public int ticketnum { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Methods
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!IsPostBack)
        {
            LoadCombos();
        }
    }

    protected void LoadCombos()
    {
        ICollection<Severity> severity = Severity.GetSeverities();
        listSeverity.DataTextField = "severitytype";
        listSeverity.DataValueField = "sevid";
        listSeverity.DataSource = severity;
        listSeverity.DataBind();

        ICollection<Status> status = Status.GetStatuses();
        liststatus.DataTextField = "statustype";
        liststatus.DataValueField = "statid";
        liststatus.DataSource = status;
        liststatus.DataBind();

        ICollection<Department> deptartment = Department.GetDepartments();
        ListDept.DataTextField = "deptname";
        ListDept.DataValueField = "deptID";
        ListDept.DataSource = deptartment;
        ListDept.DataBind();

        ICollection<Employee> employee = Employee.GetEmployee();
        ListEmp.DataTextField = "EmployeeName";
        ListEmp.DataValueField = "empID";
        ListEmp.DataSource = employee;
        ListEmp.DataBind();

        ICollection<Type> type = Type.GetIssueType();
        Listissuetype.DataTextField = "issuetype";
        Listissuetype.DataValueField = "typeid";
        Listissuetype.DataSource = type;
        Listissuetype.DataBind();
    }

    protected void btnSubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs ex)
    {


        tk.fname = fnamebox.Text;
        tk.lname = lnamebox.Text;
        tk.email = emailbox.Text;
        tk.severityID = Convert.ToInt32(listSeverity.SelectedValue);
        tk.statusID = Convert.ToInt32(liststatus.SelectedValue);
        tk.departmentID = Convert.ToInt32(ListDept.SelectedValue);
        tk.issuetype = Convert.ToInt32(Listissuetype.SelectedValue);
        tk.issuedesc = BoxDetails.Text;
        tk.Save();
        tForm.Visible = false;
        SubmitSuccess.Visible = true;


    }




    #endregion

}

}
```

I'm trying to figure out where exactly should I put

```
    SqlParameter parameterticketnum = new SqlParameter("@ticketnumber", SqlDbType.BigInt);

                parameterticketnum.Direction = ParameterDirection.Output;

                parameterticketnum.Value = ticketnum;

                cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterticketnum);

                con.Open();
                cmd.Connection = con;
                cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                cmd.ExecuteScalar();
                int tickID = (int)Convert.ToInt32(ticketnum.ToString());
                con.Close();
```

To get it to print in my Submitted Form

I'm not getting any errors. I just don't understand if I'm retrieving the ticketnumber Identity number, why is it not able to print.

All help is appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: be specific on codes and question..

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is the way you're retrieving the return value.

Instead of using ticketnum:

int tickID = (int)Convert.ToInt32(ticketnum.ToString());

Do something more like this:

int tickID = Convert.ToInt32(cmd.Parameters["@ticketnumber"].Value);

Hope this helps!